# Why does Jenkins starting my django server give me 404, but manually running the same script work properly?

Tags: python, django, bash, jenkins, fabric

This is my fabric script that runs on the jenkins server.

```
sudo('/home/myjenkins/killit.sh',pty=False)
sudo('/home/myjenkins/makedir.sh',pty=False)
sudo('/home/myjenkins/runit.sh',pty=False)
```

This kills the old server, creates a virtualenv, installs the requirements and restarts the server.

The problem is the with the script that starts the server - runit.sh :-

`nohup /home/myjenkins/devserver/dev/bin/python /home/myjenkins/devserver
/workspace/manage.py runserver --noreload 0:80 >> jenkins.out &`

When the jenkins server that starts the server and I navigate to the homepage, it gives me a 404 Page Not Found. It says /static/index.html not found. But the file exists. When I run 'sudo bash runit.sh' and I access the homepage, It works fine.

```
mkdir -p /home/myjenkins/devserver
cp -rf /home/myjenkins/workspace /home/jenkins/devserver/
cp -f /home/myjenkins/dev_settings.py /home/myjenkins/devserver/workspace/mywebsite/settings.py
cd /home/myjenkins/devserver
virtualenv -p python3 dev
cd /home/myjenkins/devserver/workspace
../dev/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Please ask me for more details if you need it.

**EDITED 9/2/18**

When I start the script from the folder containing manage.py, the server is able to serve the files. But Jenkins was starting the script from the home folder and if I also start the script from the home folder - the server is not able to find the files. look at my comment for more details. It would be great if someone could explain why this happens even though I've specified the full path in the script.

`nohup /home/myjenkins/devserver/dev/bin/python /home/myjenkins/devserver
/workspace/manage.py runserver --noreload 0:80 >> jenkins.out &`

Comment: Anything in the jenkins.out?

Comment: Is your project getting cloned or created by makedir.sh?

Comment: No it's just blank. the jenkins build output says "sudo: /home/jenkins/runit.sh out: sudo password:Finished: SUCCESS"

Comment: @karthick I've added my makedir.sh

Comment: Okay. I've had a breakthrough. I don't know why it happens, but jenkins runs the script from the home folder. Why I run it, I switch to the workspace folder which contains the manage.py file. I actually wrote the wrong command in the question. The command that I actually ran was 'sudo bash ~/runit.sh'. The django server started from the workspace folder is able to serve the files, but the django server started from the home folder is unable to serve the files. I don't know why this happens. I've solved the problem, but I'm itching to know why this happens. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` is not intended to run production-like systems, as it is not optimized for that. It is convenient you run django on live systems using a more suitable server like [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the whole deal. My django server was taking the output of the npm build from the wrong folder.

In the settings.py file, the variable `STATICFILES_DIRS` was set as:-

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('frontend/dist',)
```

instead of:-

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/dist'),)
```

Thus, when Jenkins was running the script, it was doing so from the home folder. This made Django's staticfiles finders to look at /home/myjenkins/frontend/dist instead of the relative '../frontend/dist'